# WordPress CiviCRM Map Contacts

Tags: wordpress, geocoding

WordPress v5.1.1 - CiviCRM v5.10.4 Trying to display a map of my Contacts. Created SmartGroup of all Current Members. Click Map Contacts from SmartGroup. Only displays myself on the map. Created Google API Key and set up billing (worried as I don't know how much this costs but says I get a $200 credit/mth).

Any help would be appreciated including whether or not I need this Google API to get the geocoding done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google stopped offering a free access to Map API back in June 2018 - for most organizations - the 200 credit is sufficient - [click here for examples.](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/) I believe the cost of the Geocoding API is $5.00 per 1,000 calls.

The disclaimers on the github regarding nominatim.osm.org are likely why you don't see this in core. Many extensions like these are normally found via the [web extension directory.](https://civicrm.org/extensions/openstreetmap-geocoding)

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working was that I manually installed the OSM Extension which IS NOT in the Extensions Directory (built in) and located here:

https://github.com/bjendres/de.systopia.osm

Crazy that a) the OSM Extension is not a STANDARD and BUILT IN Extension; and b) that the Google API does not work.

Comment: Sorry you had a tough time with the Google API!  I'm using it with some clients, so I know it works.  As for the "standard and built in", I would say that as a community we're moving toward the Geocoder extension, since it's a shared project between different PHP projects: https://civicrm.org/blog/eileen/improved-geocoding-in-civicrm

Comment: Will the Extension eventually be in the Main Extension Library? I am using the OSM one (manual download and install) and it works, but each time I upgrade it gets wiped out. I store it in the /Ext folder. Still, it works and I am grateful to folks like yourself and others whom work hard so that the rest of us have a great platform!

Comment: Is that `ext` folder relative to the CiviCRM root?  If so, it'd be good to change it!  I use `<webroot>/wp-content/civicrm-custom/extensions` for WP sites.  You'll need to move the files, then change the path in both **Administer » System Settings » Directories** and **Administer » System Settings » Resource URLs**.  This will keep it from getting blown away on upgrade.

Comment: Geocoder IS in the main extension library, but it's not marked for automated distribution because it hasn't been submitted for peer review.  Not a lot of folks do peer review of extensions on the regular - but it's written by Eileen McNaughton, whose CiviCRM code I trust over my own (by a lot).  It's also in production on many large installations, including Wikimedia Foundation.